# java.util.IllegalFormatFlagsException: Flags = ' '

Tags: java, hamcrest

I'm using hamcrest matchers to compare 2 `list<String>`

```
List<String> oldProductNames = (List<String>) ConfigurationManager.getBundle()
            .getProperty("productName");

Reporter.log("Unsorted Product Name : " + oldProductNames);
Collections.sort(oldProductNames);
Reporter.log("Sorted Product Name : " + oldProductNames);

List<String> sortedList = getAllProductNamesFromListing("excludeOOS");
Reporter.log("Sorted By Web Site : " + sortedList);

assertThat(oldProductNames, contains(sortedList.toArray()));
```

Output looks like :

> Unsorted Product Name : [nehatestbundlenew2, nehatestbundlenew, beurre
>   de cacahuètes 100% naturel, beurre d'amandes grillées 1 kg, beurre de
>   noix de cajou grillées 1 kg, nuts about whey™, beurre de noisettes 1
>   kg, beurre de cacahuètes aux 4 graines, beurre de noisettes grillées
>   au chocolat noir, beurre de pistache grillées 1 kg, beurre d'amandes
>   grillées au chocolat noir, beurre d'amandes - noisettes - cajou,
>   beurre de cacahuète à la noix de coco]

---

> Sorted Product Name : [beurre d'amandes - noisettes - cajou, beurre
>   d'amandes grillées 1 kg, beurre d'amandes grillées au chocolat noir,
>   beurre de cacahuète à la noix de coco, beurre de cacahuètes 100%
>   naturel, beurre de cacahuètes aux 4 graines, beurre de noisettes 1 kg,
>   beurre de noisettes grillées au chocolat noir, beurre de noix de cajou
>   grillées 1 kg, beurre de pistache grillées 1 kg, nehatestbundlenew,
>   nehatestbundlenew2, nuts about whey™]

---

> Sorted By Web Site : [beurre d'amandes - noisettes - cajou, beurre
>   d'amandes grillées 1 kg, beurre d'amandes grillées au chocolat noir,
>   beurre de cacahuète à la noix de coco, beurre de cacahuètes 100%
>   naturel, beurre de cacahuètes aux 4 graines, beurre de noisettes 1 kg,
>   beurre de noisettes grillées au chocolat noir, beurre de noix de cajou
>   grillées 1 kg, beurre de pistache grillées 1 kg, nehatestbundlenew,
>   nehatestbundlenew2, nuts about whey™]

But below error for `assertThat(oldProductNames, contains(sortedList.toArray()));`

> java.util.IllegalFormatFlagsException: Flags = ' '

Comment: wild guess, the issue could be the % sign in one of the product names

Comment: @UlugToprak, right `%` creating the issue. I've replaced this while adding product into list is working fine.

Comment: glad it's sorted, I will post an answer just to clarify why  % sign is the issue for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `assertThat(oldProductNames, contains(sortedList.toArray()));`
You are following this pattern `assertThat(actual, contains(expected));`

`oldProductNames` contains `%` signs and when passing this into the `assertThat` method you are actually passing a format specifier in.

As a result of this, immediate `space` following the said format specifier is picked up by the `java.util.IllegalFormatFlagsException` as a leading space causing this exception to be thrown.